# Will my laptop components work with minipc?

Tags: memory, sata

I have old non working (kind of unstable, some times boots, some times does not and screen flickers) [Dell XPS 15 L502x](https://valid.x86.fr/h8irya). I have two 8 GB DDR3 SODIMMs and SATA 3 SSD. The processor is Core i7 2630QM. I was somehow thinking to recuse these components and the laptop seems unstable to the extent of unusable. Can I reuse SATA SSD and DDR3 SODIMMs in the [Gigbyte BRIX GB-BACE-3160 minipc](https://www.amazon.in/GIGABYTE-GB-BACE-3160-Compact-Processor-Bluetooth/dp/B07JG5R1K5/)? It seem to support DDR3L. Will DDR3 RAM SODIMMs work?

Answer (score 0):

That won't work with that Brix.
It only accepts DDR3L SO-DIMMS, so the RAM will certainly not work.

And the CPU in that Brix is probably not replaceable. In these mini-PC's is fairly common to be soldered to the motherboard and not socketed.
Even if the CPU is replaceable it is possible the Brix doesn't have enough cooling for the i7 and/or the Bios doesn't support the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

The SSD should work. The SATA connector used for disks is identical in all form factors.

The memory *may* work, but officially it's **unsupported**. Your sticks are [DDR3](https://www.corsair.com/eu/en/Categories/Products/Memory/Mainstream-Memory/Corsair-Memory-%E2%80%94-8GB-DDR3-SODIMM-Memory/p/CMSO8GX3M1A1333C9#tab-tech-specs) rather than DDR3L, which means they need 1.5V to operate compared to 1.35V for DDR3L. The BRIX motherboard may not be able to provide 1.5V. Also note that it has only one RAM slot, so you won't be able to use both of your sticks and you won't benefit from dual-channel memory.

The J3160 CPU is quite underpowered for modern standards and it's not upgradeable. Considering that you can't reuse all of your RAM anyway, you may want to scratch this idea, sell the RAM and spend the money on something more future-proof. Desktops have socketed CPUs which can be upgraded later when performance becomes insufficient and compatible parts get cheaper.

Comment: Q1. But even if the CPUs are socketed in desktops, isnt that the newer processors doesnt fit in older sockets? Q2. I will be using this machine mainly for video straming and central storage for all my files. Wont it suffice?

Comment: @Maha Ad Q1: You're correct. But as I wrote in the answer, parts get cheaper over time, so you can upgrade to more powerful hardware than you could afford at the time. Ad Q2: I'm not sure, google around. Video transcoding is pretty demanding.